# smashing start not running ruby process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, eventmachine

I am trying to do a smashing start but it gives me this below. I go into my processes in task manager and ruby is not running. It seems to have crashed out and I am wondering what is causing this?

```
$ smashing start
    C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:18:in `unpack_sockaddr_in': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:18:in `connect'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `block in start'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:1535:in `event_callback'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:566:in `block in run_timers'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/set.rb:774:in `each'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/set.rb:774:in `each'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:563:in `run_timers'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:546:in `block in run'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:542:in `loop'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:542:in `run'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:144:in `run_machine'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in `run_command'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:in `run!'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/bin/thin:23:in `load'
            from C:/tools/ruby25/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
    Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
    Maximum connections set to 1024
    Listening on 0.0.0.0:3030, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: Yes, also happening to me. It seems that the application starts, but later on it fails with this ugly exception. I'm using windows 10 with Ruby installer + DevKit x64

Comment: Your issue is a likely related to this issue in the **thin** gem https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/353. The event machine isn't starting nicely and hence doesn't return the host/port to start up on.

Comment: I *still* have this problem, is there any quick fix? I first ran into the problem described at https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/353 and fixed it by adding "require 'em/pure_ruby'" into eventmachine.rb